# FreeTDS working, but ODBC cannot connect

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ubuntu-12.04, freetds, isql

I am trying to run connect to a MSSQL server from an Ubuntu 12.04 webserver with FreeTDS and unixODBC.

Using tsql i can connect to the server with

```
~$ tsql -S dbs3 -U <username> -P <password>
```

No problem there.

When I try to connect with isql however, I get the following error message:

```
~$ isql -v database3 <username> <password>
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My config files are as follows:

odbc.ini

```
[database3]
Driver=FreeTDS
TDS_Version=8.0
Servername=dbs3
Port=1433
Database=benchmark_res
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS v0.91
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsS.so
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/freetds.log
ForceTrave=Yes
UsageCount=1
```

freetds.conf

```
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
    # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
    text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
    host = symachine.domain.com
    port = 5000
    tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
    host = ntmachine.domain.com
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0

[dbs3]
    host = <server-ip>
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

I followed the installation guide 1. [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2012/08/freetds-quick-start.html) and 2. [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2012/08/creating-datasource-with-freetds-and.html?showComment=1376395395571)

Why isn't isql connecting properly?
My guess is that the mistake is super obvious but I'm just too stupid to see it :D

Answer (score 13):

The issue was this line in odbc.ini

```
[database3] must be [dbs3] in your case.
```

For those that are also having this problem, Check also the

```
ServerName  = *Points to the name of the server configured in freetds.conf*
```

Comment: If fixing this didn't solve the problem, what would you think to do next?

Answer (score 1):

If odbc does not find the datasource it means you are providing the wrong one

You are probably trying to connect to `dbs3` which will fail if you don't have it  in odbc.ini

You should connect to `[database3]` for ODBC

```
isql -v database3 <username> <password>
```

Comment: That's what I am doing. I use dbs3 with tsql:
tsql -S dbs3 -U <username> -P <username>.

Using isql the way you mentiones returns these errors

Comment: Ok have you added database3 to your host file

Comment: No, because from my understanding, it should be resolved with the IP I entered in the freetds.conf

Comment: both freetds and odbc

Comment: ODBC: `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc`

freeTDS: I built that from source. I linked the description I followed in the original question

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I found out that you have to execute the following after each modification of `odbc.ini`:

```
odbcinst -i -s -f /etc/odbc.ini
```

After that, tested this :

```
isql -v SERVER USER PWD
```

and I got this output:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```