# Ubuntu Shiny server connecting to Jet/ACE databases

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc, shiny-server

Can it be done: Reading data stored in an MS Access (.accdb) database, from within Shiny apps running on Ubuntu Shiny server?

We have no knowledge of SQL Server Express. We have our data organized in simple MS Access databases, and want to deploy our Shiny apps (who visualize this data) on an Ubuntu Shiny server.

It all works on our local Windows machines, but how to make it also work with an Ubuntu Shiny server?

I understand that with our minimal knowledge of database systems, it is not straightforward to go porting our databases to SQL Server Express.

Thanks in advance for your expertise!

Comment: An Access database should be accessible using `ODBC`. The `RODBC` package would allow you to connect to your database once an appropriate `DSN` was given.

Comment: @jdharrison Thanks for your comment. Indeed, we have things working here on Windows machine with RODBC and the appropriate DSN's. But on Ubuntu machine we should create the DSN with a tool like FreeTDS? I find nowhere how to configure FreeTDS for MS Access, only MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of a job setting this up myself.  I had to take info from several sources to get all the required packages – the following is a list of good info sources:
http://guywyant.info/log/206/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-ubuntu/
http://driftharmony.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/connecting-ubuntu-804-to-microsoft-sql-server/
https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/wiki/FreeTDS
[FreeTDS working, but ODBC cannot connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232386/freetds-working-but-odbc-cannot-connect)

The 3 files were ultimately configured thus:

```
Detail of file:  /etc/odbc.ini
[NameThis]
Driver = FreeTDS
TDS_Version=8.0
Servername = YourServer
Port = 1433
Database = testing
Trace = No
```

Detail of file: /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

Detail of file:  /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $

# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same  name is found in the installation directory.  

# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes 
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
    text size = 64512

# Test Kx
[NameThis]
    host = YOUR IP
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.2
```