# Access SQL Server from Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm trying to access a SQL Server database running on another machine on the network, from an Alpine Docker image, running on an Ubuntu machine. So far, I can access the database from the Ubuntu machine, but I can't connect to it from inside the container. By setting `network_mode: host` inside my `docker-compose.yml` file, I can ping the SQL Server database, but I still can't connect to it with `isql`, `tsql`, or the Python module `pyodbc`.

I can use `tsql` to locate the database from the host and the container, but I can't connect to the database from the container.

```
# works fine from host and container
tsql -H apex-data.apex.local -L

# only works from host
tsql -S apex-data -p 1433 -U condor
# or alternatively with /etc/odbc.ini
isql APEXDSN
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# update apk repo
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add unixodbc unixodbc-dev && \
    apk add freetds && \
    apk add build-base

WORKDIR /usr/src/project

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini

COPY project ./
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: "nf-app"
    command: python3 app.py
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/project
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "1433:1433"
    network_mode: host
```

Here is the `odbcinst.ini` file:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0

[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
ForceTrace = Yes
TraceFile = /usr/src/project/logs/odbc.log
```

Comment: And what hostname are you using to connect to SQL from inside container?

Comment: It's a domain name on the network, something like `apex-data.apex.local`. I also tried using the IP address, but that didn't work an better.

Comment: As soon as your container is running in `host` network mode, you connect to SQL with `localhost` from inside

Comment: Even if the IP address of the SQL server is something else, like 192.168.xxx.xxx?

Comment: Your SQL runs on same machine as `docker`? If yes, the actual IP does not matter if you are using network mode `host`

Comment: No, the SQL server runs on another machine on the network.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, didnt get it from question

Comment: Did you check /etc/odbcinst.ini is accessible by the app and/or odbc is working fine ? It seems like the problem is not related with Docker networking.

Comment: Btw `host` network mode is incompatible with `port forwarding`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: @grapes I saw that `host` mode doesn't allow links, but I didn't know about port forwarding, thanks.

Comment: @SamiAltundag how would I check /etc/odbcint.ini to confirm that it's working okay?

Comment: You can add these lines to odbcinst.ini  file and check logs file in Docker I think. [ODBC]
 
Trace=yes
 
TraceFile=/path/to/file/name.log
 
[ODBC Drivers]

Comment: @SamiAltundag okay, I added the logging, but it doesn't provide much more than the error message I saw in the `tsql` output: `[[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source]`

Comment: If you use Host name, it works.  If you use, -S it does not work. So something should be wrong with odbc config. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232386/freetds-working-but-odbc-cannot-connect ? Sorry I could not help more.

Comment: @SamiAltundag that looks very promising! Thank you for the link!